# MonadResource for reading files with error handling

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, conduit

I'm creating a Conduit that will read binary files. Stuff can go wrong, so I need a monad with some error handling; for now `Maybe` is good enough.

I'd like to use `sourceFile`, which requires that the conduit monad be a `MonadResource`, and this is the crux of the problem.

I see from [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.9/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html) that e.g. `MaybeT m` has an instance, but it requires `m` to already be a `MonadResource`; in fact this is true of all the instances. With my limited understanding this kinda sounds like a chicken-and-egg thing, requiring that I write a `MonadResource` instance by hand no matter what?

I assume that to read files, my monad has to contain IO. So does all this mean that I have to write a `MonadResource` instance for `MaybeT IO`? If so, any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: `(MonadThrow m, MonadBase IO m, MonadIO m, Applicative m) => MonadResource (ResourceT m)` is not recursive.

Comment: Aha, missed that. Time to dive in and learn how `ResourceT` works I guess..

Comment: simply some form of `main = runResourceT . runConduit $ sourceFile …` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use `tryC` for example:

```
module Main (main) where

import           Conduit
import           Control.Exception (SomeException)
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Resource as R
import           Data.Monoid ((<>))
import           System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [fname] <- getArgs
  r <- R.runResourceT . runConduit . tryC $ sourceFile fname .| await >>= pure
  case r of
    Left e -> putStrLn $ "Failed to read file content with " <> show (e :: SomeException)
    Right r' -> putStrLn $ "File content: " <> show r'
```

Then you get:

```
[nix-shell:/tmp]$ ghc -Wall M.hs && ./M /tmp/doesnt_exist
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( M.hs, M.o )
Linking M ...
Failed to read file content with /tmp/doesnt_exist: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

[nix-shell:/tmp]$ ghc -Wall M.hs && ./M /tmp/hello-file
File content: Just "Hello world!
```